# mybatis column name conflict?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mapping, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis for persistence layer in my project.

I have two tables in  mySql db, paytransaction and paymenttype, the definition is as follows:

```
PayTransaction          PaymentType

Field                   Field
-------------           -------
id                  
payment_state       
creation_date       
update_date     
payment_type ----FK---->id
payment_id              description
```

So, a paytransaction has associated a paymenttype through payment_type column (foreign Key).

The definition of my mappers is as follows:

PayTransaction

```
<resultMap id="payTransactionPaymentTypeResultMap" type="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPayTransaction" >
    <id     column="id"                     property="id"                   javaType="long"/>
    <result column="payment_state"          property="payment_state"        javaType="string"/>
    <result column="creation_date"          property="creation_date"        javaType="date"/>
    <result column="update_date"            property="update_date"          javaType="date"/>
    <result column="payment_id"             property="payment_id"           javaType="long"/>
    <association column="payment_type" property="paymentType" javaType="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPaymentType" resultMap="com.XXX.payplatform.model.dao.interfaces.IDAOPaymentType.paymentTypeResultMap"/>
</resultMap>
```

PaymentType

```
<resultMap id="paymentTypeResultMap" type="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPaymentType" >
    <id     column="id"                     property="id"                   javaType="long"/>
    <result column="description"            property="description"          javaType="string"/>
</resultMap>
```

The SQL JOIN Statement is:

```
<sql id="joinPayTransactionPaymentType">
    select paytransaction.id, paytransaction.payment_state, paytransaction.creation_date,paytransaction.update_date, paytransaction.payment_id, 
    paymenttype.id, paymenttype.description
    from paytransaction
    INNER JOIN paymenttype ON paymenttype.id = paytransaction.payment_type 
</sql>
```

The problem comes with the columns named "id" both in paytransaction and paymenttype tables. When mapping the objects, the same value goes to the ids fields, i.e. if paytransaction has an id of 39, the id of paymenttype in the java object after mapping will be also 39 when it is 3 in db.

I've tried writting alias, like:

```
<sql id="joinPayTransactionPaymentType">
    select paytransaction.id AS "paytransaction.id", paytransaction.payment_state as payment_state, paytransaction.creation_date as creation_date,paytransaction.update_date as update_date, paytransaction.payment_id as payment_id, 
    paymenttype.id AS "paymenttype.id", paymenttype.description as description
    from paytransaction
    INNER JOIN paymenttype ON paymenttype.id = paytransaction.payment_type 
</sql>
```

But there is no result. The only solution I think will work is changing the name of the columns in db, such like "paymenttype_id" and "paytransaction_id".

Is there any solution or this is a mybatis bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same property names is not a problem for MyBatis as long as you are able to map *definite* columns (*or column aliases*) to these properties. When you give an alias to the resulting columns, you should give the same column name to the `paymentTypeResultMap` too. It should work then.

```
<resultMap id="payTransactionPaymentTypeResultMap" type="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPayTransaction" >
    <id     column="id"                     property="id"                   javaType="long"/>
    <result column="payment_state"          property="payment_state"        javaType="string"/>
    <result column="creation_date"          property="creation_date"        javaType="date"/>
    <result column="update_date"            property="update_date"          javaType="date"/>
    <result column="payment_id"             property="payment_id"           javaType="long"/>
    <association column="payment_type" property="paymentType" javaType="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPaymentType" resultMap="com.XXX.payplatform.model.dao.interfaces.IDAOPaymentType.paymentTypeResultMap"/>
</resultMap>
```

...

```
<resultMap id="paymentTypeResultMap" type="com.XXX.payplatform.model.to.impl.TOPaymentType" >
    <id     column="paymenttype_id"                     property="id"                   javaType="long"/>
    <result column="description"            property="description"          javaType="string"/>
</resultMap>
```

...

```
<sql id="joinPayTransactionPaymentType">
    select paytransaction.id, paytransaction.payment_state as payment_state, paytransaction.creation_date as creation_date,paytransaction.update_date as update_date, paytransaction.payment_id as payment_id, 
    paymenttype.id AS paymenttype_id, paymenttype.description as description
    from paytransaction
    INNER JOIN paymenttype ON paymenttype.id = paytransaction.payment_type 
</sql>
```

Comment: Thanks Yigitalp! But if I correctly understand, i NEED to change the paymenttype "id" column in db and then the column definition in the mapper, Am I right?

The problem here is both paymenttype and paytransaction "id" columns are named "id".

Comment: I mean, it is not a property conflict, but it is a column name conflict. I edited the title, sorry.

Comment: You don't need to change the name of the column in DB. You can write your queries like "SELECT id AS paymenttype_id FROM paymenttype". That solves the column name conflicts. MyBatis does not need to know what are the 'real' names of the columns, what matters is the result sets coming from the queries. The "joinPayTransactionPaymentType" sql will return 'paymenttype.id' as 'paymenttype_id'; 'paytransaction.id' as 'id'. Then MyBatis will map 'paymenttype_id' to the 'id' field in 'TOPaymentType' object; 'id' to 'id' field in 'TOPayTransaction' object.

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the reply. But I am doing that and i am getting mapping errors.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can update the question with the errors you get.

Comment: Hello, Yigitalp. Finally I chose to change the database column name. The problems were each columnd that didn't matched were null in the java object. Changing the column name in db solved the problems.